# Issue about appStoreReceiptURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to convert my paid app to free version with IAP , so basically I need to check if users bought previous version then unlock IAP item , I am not sure I am doing right here or not ! even is it possible to check and track 'appStoreReceiptURL' in development process ? here is my code :

```
  NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSLog(@"receiptUrl %@",[url path]);
    NSError* err = nil;
    if (![url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err]){
        SKReceiptRefreshRequest* request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:nil];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
    }


-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest*)request{
    if([request isKindOfClass:[SKReceiptRefreshRequest class]]){

        NSLog(@"YES, You purchased this app");
    }
}



-(void)request:(SKRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"NO, you need to buy it ");

}
```

Now I am able to login with my Apple ID,and after I signed in it tells me `YES, You purchased this app"`, and yes I really bought my app ! ,  I am going to make sure everything is alright . 
Does this process should happen in every update ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same thing right now.

Comment: @TomKrones Yes  , check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
```

Don't forget to add its delegates

```
<SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>
```

Payment Validation

```
- (IBAction)boughtIt:(id)sender {

    NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSLog(@"receiptUrl %@",[url path]);
    NSError* err = nil;
    if (![url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err]){
        SKReceiptRefreshRequest* request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:nil];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
         _activity.hidden = NO;
    }

}



-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest*)request{
    if([request isKindOfClass:[SKReceiptRefreshRequest class]]){

        NSLog(@"YES, You purchased this app");

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congrats !" message:@"Welcome To The World Of Dinosaurs" delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isPurchased"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        _activity.hidden = YES;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}



- (void)request:(SKRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry !" message:@"It seems you did not purchase this app before, if you like to unlock all content and features please purchase Paleontologist Pack" delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];

    _activity.hidden = YES;

//    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"NO, you need to buy it ");

}
```

This works only if a user `PURCHASED` the application , it doesn't work for redeem codes

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know how to test this code?  I know it won't work on the simulator but do I need to use a distribution provisioning profile when I build the app?

Comment: You test it and it works?  Cool looking app though.  :)

Comment: Thanks for code.
Since the code runs at an already downloaded app, wouldn't it recognize it as purchased always?
It would be good to know when did the user download/purchase the app